# Why does readelf show "System V" as my OS instead of Linux?

Tags: linux, elf

I compiled a small C program (2 lines of codes) with gcc to try to understand ELF file format. 
Doing a `readelf -h` on the object file, I have in the header :

```
OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
```

I am using Fedora, so why isn't it Linux instead ?

**Edit**: I compiled

```
int main(){
  int x = 0;
  x++;
}
```

with `gcc -o main.o -c main.c`. My gcc version is

```
gcc (GCC) 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4)
```

Comment: Please show us i) the code you compiled ii) the output of `gcc --version` and iii) the exact command you used to compile it.

Comment: I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I just did `readelf -h /bin/ls` on debian gnu/linux. It also showed `OS/ABI: UNIX - System V`. My guess is that the ABI is used on more than one kernel, not just linux. I also know that linux supports more than one ABI.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#File_header) says _It [the OSABI field in the ELF header] is often set to 0 [SysV] regardless of the target platform_

Comment: This field tells if the ELF file is using any OS specific extensions, the default is 0. [More detailled description here](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch4.eheader.html)(at EI_OSABI).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, that's probably the answer. Maybe good to post it as one. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are few differences between ELF executables on different platforms. “UNIX - System V” is the common ground; [System V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_V) is where the [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format came from. The corresponding numerical value is 0. This value indicates that the executable doesn't use any OS-specific extension. Debian GNU/Linux, at least, configures GCC/binutils to generate executables with this field set to 0 by default.

Comment: And the ELF standard says 0 means "ELFOSABI_NONE 0 No extensions or unspecified" http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/2003-12-17/ch4.eheader.html